# How to Tag @ someone in Slack using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, tags, slack

I've used the following PS to send a message to a Slack channel, using webhook and it is working fine! Now, I'd like to **@someone** in the end of the message sent!
When I tried to use it as a **$variable**, it didn't work. Just print the @someone on the message as plain text but not tagged him.

```
> $servername = "SERVER"
$username = "USER"
$password = "PWD"
$Date = Get-Date

$result = Invoke-SQLCmd -Querytimeout 120 -ServerInstance $serverName -Username $username -Password $password -InputFile "C:\directory\script.sql"

$text = "$text Server: $servername"
$value = $result.field
$text = "$text`nField Name: $value"

$text = "$text`nDate: $Date"

$payload = @{
 "channel" = "#slack_channel"
  "text" = "$text"
}

$hook="https://hooks.slack.com/services/WEBHOOK"

Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Body (ConvertTo-Json -Compress -InputObject $payload) -Method Post -Uri $hookBlockquote
```

Comment: As an aside: In PowerShell, you never need to enclose variable references in `"..."` (except - for non-string values - if you want to force up-front stringification). Unlike in shells such as Bash, even variable values with embedded spaces are passed correctly without `"..."` enclosure.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware! Will start using this way!